# Android: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android

I am trying to open a huge image from the web, on the second item when i try to load the image... i get the below error.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    progress.dismiss();

    try {
        JSONObject documentRoot = new JSONObject(result);
        String data = documentRoot.getString("Data");
        if (data.length() < 10) {
            Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "This is not a valid document", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        } else
            openPDF(data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Document could not be opened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
}
```

I am getting error in `JSONObject documentRoot = new JSONObject(result);` this line.

```
 06-14 19:54:22.218: E/XXX(16949): Uncaught exception is: 06-14
 19:54:22.218: E/XXX(16949): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError 06-14 19:54:22.218: E/XXX(16949):     at
 java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
 06-14 19:54:22.218: E/XXX(16949):     at
 java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:162)
 06-14 19:54:22.218: E/XXX(16949):     at
 java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:311) 06-14
 19:54:22.218: E/XXX(16949):     at
 org.json.JSONTokener.nextString(JSONTokener.java:224) 06-14
 19:54:22.218: E/XXX(16949):     at
 org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:107) 06-14
 19:54:22.218: E/XXX(16949):     at
 org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:385) 06-14
 19:54:22.218: E/XXX(16949):     at
 org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:100) 06-14
 19:54:22.218: E/XXX(16949):     at
 org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154) 06-14 19:54:22.218:
 E/XXX(16949):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
 06-14 19:54:22.218: E/XXX(16949):     at
 com.patient.Activity$DocumentsShowAsyncTask.onPostExecute(DocumentViewerActivity2.java:273)
 06-14 19:54:22.218: E/XXX(16949):     at
 com.patient.Activity$DocumentsShowAsyncTask.onPostExecute(DocumentViewerActivity2.java:1)
 06-14 19:54:22.218: E/XXX(16949):     at
 android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631) 06-14 19:54:22.218:
 E/XXX(16949):     at
 android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177) 06-14
 19:54:22.218: E/XXX(16949):     at
 android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
 06-14 19:54:22.218: E/XXX(16949):     at
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 06-14
 19:54:22.218: E/XXX(16949):     at
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 06-14 19:54:22.218:
 E/XXX(16949):     at
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4928) 06-14
 19:54:22.218: E/XXX(16949):     at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-14
 19:54:22.218: E/XXX(16949):     at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 06-14 19:54:22.218:
 E/XXX(16949):     at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
 06-14 19:54:22.218: E/XXX(16949):     at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558) 06-14
 19:54:22.218: E/XXX(16949):     at
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you base64 encoded the entire pdf into json?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the data is just too large to hold in a String. How are you representing this PDF that it can be loaded from a String anyway? maybe it's a better idea to provide a URL in the JSON, and then you can use generic downloader code to get the PDF, without storing too much data in memory at a time.

Comment: Is there anyway without using an URL in the JSON?

Comment: You could do a standard HTTP Download, reading from an InputStream, chunk-by-chunk and converting to PDF or image in-line and probably write to a file. This would probably require you parse the JSON manually, however. Once the PDF is downloaded/converted, you can open it from the filesystem.